# Repeat a vector on a dataframe

Tags: r, vector, data.table, repeat

I want to add a column to my datatable based on a vector. However my datatable is having 20 rows and my vector is having 7 values. I want the datatable to be repeated 7 times such that each 20 rows has one value from the vector. This might be simple but I am not able to get how to do this.

Some sample data -

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(9901)

#### create the sample variables for creating the data
group <- c(1:7)

brn <- sample(1:10,20,replace = T)
period <- c(101:120)

df1 <- data.table(cbind(brn,period))
```

So in this case I want to add a column group. datatable would now have 140 rows. 20 rows for group 1 then 20 rows for group 2 and so on.....

Comment: I'm having problems understanding the task. Maybe `df1[CJ(group, period), on = .(period)]`?

Comment: @Roland, exactly this is what I was looking for....great !! how did this happen in a single line.... I was checking what CJ mean and it says cross join based on the product of vectors.....would this work if my data had more columns say another 10 columns but I wanted it to be based on let say period....?

Comment: You example data has one additional column. The number of additional columns is not relevant for this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you want this:

```
df1[CJ(group, period), on = .(period)]
#     brn period group
#  1:   3    101     1
#  2:   9    102     1
#  3:   9    103     1
#  4:   5    104     1
#  5:   5    105     1
# ---                 
#136:   9    116     7
#137:   7    117     7
#138:  10    118     7
#139:   2    119     7
#140:   7    120     7
```

`CJ` creates a data.table resulting from the cartesian join of the vectors passed to it. This data.table is then joined with `df1` based on the column specified by `on`.

Comment: Really, really great. I didn't know `CJ`. `data.table` continues to amaze me.

Comment: Thank you Roland !! Learned something new today, how one can use CJ !!

Answer (score 1):

I would (1) repeat each number in `group` 20 times to create the datasets in a list and
(2) join them:

```
AllLists<-apply(as.data.frame(group),1,function(x) cbind(x,df1))
do.call( "rbind",AllLists)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `data.table`. Is that what you are looking for?

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), times = 7),
           ][,group := rep(group, each = 20)]
```

But Rolands solution in the comments is definitly more elegant.